# i am facing problems while running a code on GNU GCC compiler while it's working fine on VC++ compiler

Tags: c, malloc

```
printf("\n enter your choice\n 1 to ask user for the size of game board\n 2 tp get input from a file\n");
scanf("%d",&choice);
if(choice==1)
{
    printf("\n enter number of rows and columns");
    scanf("%d%d",&row,&col);
    mat=(char**)malloc(row*sizeof(char));
    label=(char**)malloc(row*sizeof(char));
    for(i=0;i<row;i++)
    {
        mat[i]=(char*)malloc(col*sizeof(char));
        label[i]=(char*)malloc(col*sizeof(char));
    }

    for(i=0;i<row;i++)
    {

        for(j=0;j<col;j++)
        {
            temp=rand()%5;

            mat[i][j]=color_codes[temp];
            label[i][j]=' ';
        }

    }
}
```

this  C Language statements is running fine on my visual studio IDE, but when i try to run this same statements on CODE BLOCKS IDE this thing suddenly crashes .Any kind of help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Yes, and you need to say which part it crashes at. Are we just supposed to magically know?

Comment: And you need to further tell us the declarations of **all variables**.

Comment: i think Seven bits you should see a answer below which might make you realise that knowledge comes from experiences

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an easy way to avoid this bug, where you multiply with the wrong value, when doing a malloc:

**→ Always multiply with the sizeof the type of the array element, `sizeof(*var)` ←**.

```
 char **mat;

 mat = malloc (row * sizeof(*mat));
```

This way you'll never ever get the multiplications wrong again. Another advantage: Should you decide to change the type of `mat` to say, `double`, all you need to change is one place: its declaration.

And you shouldn't cast the malloc return value. [It's been hashed to death on SO why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: +1 for the array variable in sizeof and for throwing unnecessary casts away.

Answer (score 1):

You are not allocating enough memory:

```
mat=(char**)malloc(row*sizeof(char));
label=(char**)malloc(row*sizeof(char));
```

Each item in the arrays is a pointer to char (`char*`), so you should multiply by `sizeof(char*)`:

```
mat=(char**)malloc(row*sizeof(char*));
label=(char**)malloc(row*sizeof(char*));
```

Comment: And you **shouldn't cast** the malloc return value. It's been hashed to death on SO why.

Comment: thnks buddy really helpful

Answer (score 1):

the two lines

```
mat=(char**)malloc(row*sizeof(char));
label=(char**)malloc(row*sizeof(char));
```

look not sane to me, you are trying to allocate an array of pointers to char but you specify only the size for a simple char. a pointer usually needs more that one byte.

so what you probably need is

```
mat=(char**)malloc(row*sizeof(char*));
label=(char**)malloc(row*sizeof(char*));
```

**Note** that it is not necessary to cats the result of `malloc` since in `C` a `void*` can be implicitly casted to any type.

So

```
mat=malloc(row*sizeof(char*));
label=malloc(row*sizeof(char*));
```

will work fine too.

Comment: And you **shouldn't cast** the malloc return value. It's been hashed to death on SO why.